# Most efficient/elegant/robust solution to pass data from an event thread to a constantly running thread in non-blocking way (C++20)

Tags: c++, multithreading, event-loop, condition-variable

I am working on a research project, essentially a Windows window that displays a sequence of images at 30 fps. I have been initially using GLFW. However, the issue with the API (despite being super handy) is that when a user moves the window by clicking and dragging the window title bar or when the user keeps the mouse pressed on the lower-right corner of the window (resizing handle) without moving the mouse, the content of the window is not refreshed (due to the modal nature of Windows which doesn't release the focus on this particular case if I get it right).

So I need to create two threads: one for the processing loop (processing the image and displaying them to the screen every 1/30th of a second) and one that processes the events (mouse). Because in this project, I can't use the GLFW callback functions to capture the events (my constraint), I need to use the native Windows API. But to simplify the code, I will just be faking the creation of events. The idea is to capture the events in the main thread, pushing them to a queue. Then the thread responsible for processing and displaying the images gets the event queue, unqueue (and processes) the events, then do its stuff for the image, wait for 1/30th of a second (minus all the time it took to do the stuff above), and keep going.

The code below seems to work.

- Every time an event if fired, the `handle_event` function is called. It locks the mutex, and add the event to an `event_queue`. The mutex is unlocked when we return from the function.
- The processing thread, gets the lock, unqueue the event, process the event, etc.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <queue>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

std::mutex m;

struct Event
{
    int msg;
};

std::queue<Event> event_queue;

void handle_event()
{
    std::cerr << "new event " << std::endl;
    std::lock_guard lock(m);
    event_queue.push({0});
}

using one_cycle = std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, std::ratio<1, 30>>;
auto time_point = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + one_cycle{0};

void constantly_running_proc()
{
    while (1) {
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(m);
            std::cerr << "event queue size: " << event_queue.size() << std::endl;
            while (!event_queue.empty()) {
                Event e = event_queue.back();
                event_queue.pop();
                //do_something_with_event(e);
            }
        }
        
        // process the events
        // ...

        // process the current frame
        // ...

        time_point += one_cycle{1};
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(time_point);
        
        //display_frame();
    }
}

int main() 
{
    std::thread t(constantly_running_proc);
    while (1) {
        handle_event();
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(100ms * rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

1. First does this seem correct to you? Do you see any issue with this code?
2. While it seems to work in practice, the `constantly_running_proc` is always getting the lock on the mutex to access the event queue in a thread-safe manner, even it is a waste if the queue is empty. That's no big deal, probably. But since for this exercise, I am trying to be as efficient as the language allows it to be (it needs to say within the 1/30th of a second, and processing of the images can be heavy - saving cycles is probably a good thing in this context. I am also learning. I have been thinking and trying to use `condition_variable`. I tried this:

```
std::condition_variable cv;

void handle_event()
{
    std::cerr << "new event " << std::endl;
    std::lock_guard lock(m);
    event_queue.push({0});
    cv.notify_one();
}

void constantly_running_proc2()
{
    while (1) {
        
        // process the current frame
        // ...

        time_point += one_cycle{1};
        std::unique_lock lock(m);
        if (cv.wait_until(lock, time_point, []() { return !event_queue.empty(); })) {
            std::cerr << "event queue size: " << event_queue.size() << std::endl;
            while (!event_queue.empty()) {
                Event e = event_queue.back();
                event_queue.pop();
                //do_something_with_event(e);
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_until(time_point);
        }
        else {
            // timeout - nothing to do
        }
        
        //display_frame();
    }
}
```

I assume this would work too, but adding another `std::this_thread::sleep_until` inside the `if (cv.wait_until)` block seems overkill.

I would very much appreciate to learn from C++ experts / gurus on this problem (which I hope many people will like to find an answer to in the future).

## Edit 1

Thanks a lot to @HansPassant (who has almost 1M in reputation; I didn't even think this could exist)) for suggesting the producer-consumer model (with a link to a wiki page) in the comment.

[Wiki Producer-Consumer Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem)

While I implemented the first version of the model given on the Wiki page, I would need a different implementation. Here is why:

This model works when the consumer "runs as fast as the producer". Sometimes, the producer is busy, and the consumer fills up the buffer with events; sometimes, the producer doesn't do much, and so the consumer has time to consume the data (and the buffer gets emptied). All fine.

However, in my case, the producer can only "consume" the data once every 1/30th of a second. And so if the producer produces a lot of events in a short period, the buffer will always be full and the consumer will only have time to remove one event at time (once per cycle).

Here is the code to demonstrate this (uncomment the `sleep_until` in `constantly_running_proc` to see then what happens when the consumer is "slow"):

```
#include <semaphore>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

#include <atomic>

#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

constexpr uint32_t N = 32; // max numb. of events that can be queued / and unqueued at once
std::counting_semaphore<N> number_of_queued_positions{0};
std::counting_semaphore<N> number_of_empty_positions{N};
std::mutex buffer_manip;

struct Event
{
    int msg;
};

std::queue<Event> event_queue;

using frame = std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, std::ratio<1, 30>>;
auto time_point = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + frame{0};

std::atomic<bool> keep_running = true;

// consumer
void constantly_running_proc()
{
    while (keep_running) {
        // do some work that's roughly somewhere between 10 to 15ms
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms + 5ms * rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);
        
        number_of_queued_positions.acquire(); // decr.
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(buffer_manip);
            std::cerr << "Num events (before): " << event_queue.size() << std::endl;
            //event_queue = std::queue<Event>();
            //while (!event_queue.empty()) {
            //  Event e = event_queue.back();
                event_queue.pop();
            //}
            std::cerr << "Num events (after): " << event_queue.size() << std::endl;
            
        }
        number_of_empty_positions.release();
        
        //time_point += frame{10};
        //std::this_thread::sleep_until(time_point);
        
        // display frame
        std::cerr << "consumer thread not blocked" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(constantly_running_proc);
    uint32_t counter = 0;
    // producer
    while (1) {
        number_of_empty_positions.acquire(); // decrement counter or blocks until it can
        {
            std::lock_guard lock(buffer_manip);
            event_queue.push({0});
            std::cerr << "new event" << std::endl;
        }
        number_of_queued_positions.release(); // increment internal counter and unblocks acquires
        if (++counter > 2000000) 
            break;
        //std::this_thread::sleep_for(50ms * rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);
    }
    
    keep_running = false;
    
    return 0;
}
```

This is not ideal considering the requirements (imagine the event is a "get the window resized". The implementation is simple, elegant and seems to work). Still, it'd need the queue of events to be entirely emptied on each consumer cycle.

I will try the other solution suggested in the wiki ("Without semaphores or monitors" section), which seems that it could solve this issue, but if you have any additional comments/feedback/suggestions so far, please...

## Edit 2

As suggested above, I tried the solution proposed at the end of the wiki page by adapting it. As mentioned earlier, the consumer cannot be blocked while waiting for the event queue to be filled in with N max events (the version on the wiki page). Here is this adapted version:

```
#include <semaphore>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

#include <atomic>

#include <queue>
#include <iostream>

#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

constexpr uint32_t N = 8;
std::atomic<int> count = 0;

struct Event
{
    int msg;
};

Event event_queue[N];

using frame = std::chrono::duration<std::int64_t, std::ratio<1, 30>>;
auto time_point = std::chrono::steady_clock::now() + frame{0};

std::atomic<bool> keep_running = true;
std::mutex m;

// consumer
void constantly_running_proc()
{
    int num_events;
    Event e[N];
    while (keep_running) {
        if (count) {
            num_events = count;
            std::lock_guard lock(m);
            std::cerr << "consuming " << count << " events " << std::endl;
            // copy events
            memcpy(e, event_queue, sizeof(Event) * count);
            count = 0;
        }
        
        for (uint32_t i = 0; i < num_events; ++i) {
            std::cerr << e[i].msg << std::endl;
        }
        
        // do some work
        {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(10ms + 5ms * rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);
        }
        
        time_point += frame{2};
        std::this_thread::sleep_until(time_point);
        
        std::cerr << "consumer thread still running" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t(constantly_running_proc);
    uint32_t counter = 0;
    
    uint32_t tail = 0;
    // producer
    while (keep_running) {
        while (count == N)
            ; // busy waiting
        std::cerr << "adding new event: " <<  count << std::endl;
        event_queue[count] = Event({count});
        count++;
        if (++counter > 100) 
            keep_running = false;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(50ms * rand() / (float)RAND_MAX);
    }
    
    t.join();
    
    return 0;
}
```

This requires 1 atomic and 1 mutex call. The atomic is used in the producer thread to wait if the atomic counter equals the maximum number of events N that can be stored. The consumer grabs the events on each cycle if the atomic counter is greater than 0.

Do you see any issue with this (the number of queued events is fixed ahead of time, so it's not as flexible as using a `std::queue`)? Do you have any better method you could suggest?

Comment: I think you may have over-simplified your example. For instance, the `while (!event_queue.empty()) event_queue.pop();` loop appears useless. I'd expect the event to be processed before it is discarded. If the goal is to empty out the queue, consider move-assigning an empty queue to it rather than looping.

Comment: @user4581301. Ah I knew this was going to be a problem. I mentioned in my (original - now edited) text that I was just popping to keep the example simple, but of course, the event would be processed. I have changed the code to make it clear now and avoid that possible confusion. However you point something interesting about using move-assignment / `std::move`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem

Comment: Note that sometimes the move-assign's not what you want either. If you swap with an empty the now-full queue can be destroyed outside the critical section.

Comment: Keep all the image "processing/updating" away from the main thread.  On a background thread : Use double buffering to update image buffers one by one (offscreen bitmaps). Your paint handler then only has to blit the front buffer when repainting is needed.  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering)

Comment: @PepijnKramer - Thank you. It seems that this is what I am already doing? Whether I do this in the main thread or a seperate thread, I am uploading the image to the back buffer, and then calling swap buffer (present chain in my case) at the very end. But this doesn't solve my problem which is that the render thread needs to know when the window for instance is resized so I can reset the resources (GPU) used to process and display the frames.

Comment: @user4581301 " If you swap with an empty the now-full queue can be destroyed outside the critical section". Yes I thought about this. So you need to copy-assign the values first, but then can reset the event queue using move assignment with an empty queue instead of pop.

Comment: No copying involved. construct an empty garbage queue, swap the garbage queue with the shared queue in the critical section because swap's really cheap, often just exchanging a few pointers, now the shared queue is empty and whatever the destruction cost of the messages can be done outside of the critical section by letting the garbage queue go out of scope. Slightly more complicated than simply assigning an empty queue to the shared queue, but could get out of the critical section faster if the message destruction is costly.